install/enable sqlsrv/pdo_sqlsrv php8.1 on AlmaLinux v9.4.0
The hostgator server updated the linux system from CentOs to Almalinux and now I need to install the sqlsrv drivers again as I only get the error could not find driver
What I've done so far is move these 2 files to the /opt/cpanel/ea-php81/root/lib64/php/modules folder on the server
SQLSRV_8.1_NTS.so
PDO_SQLSRV_8.1_NTS.so
Then I put these 2 lines in php.ini
extension=SQLSRV_8.1_NTS.so
extension=PDO_SQLSRV_8.1_NTS.so
I restarted the server.
PHPinfo looked like this


The page that connects to the database only displays this message:
could not find driver
The PHP code is this:
$drive = 'sqlsrv';
$server = 'host.server.here';
$port = '1443';
$server = $port !== '1443' && is_string($port) ? $server .= ", $port": $server;
$database = 'name_database';
$user = 'user_here';
$pass = 'pass_here';

$pdoConfig  = $drive . ":". "Server=" . $server . ";";
$pdoConfig .= "Database=".$database.";";

try {
    if(!isset($connection)){
    $connection =  new PDO($pdoConfig, $user, $pass);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $connection;
}
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    return null;
}


I managed to install the driver. After digging a lot in cpanel whm I discovered that it has a MODULE INSTALLER and in this installer there is PHP PECL which allows you to use the commands that install the drivers. The same command line didn't work in the terminal so I tried manually passing the file into the folder.
I ran these 2 commands only.
install sqlsrv
install pdo_sqlsrv

